# Is there any difference where style tag is located (head vs body)

Tags: html, css

Is there any difference (in speed/order of applying) where style tag is located:

1) head 
2) body at the beginning
3) body at the end

It is more interesting the case when the style tag (with embedded css content) added dynamically with javascript during runtime.

Comment: 1. Google can give you the answer. 2. put in the head. 3. so the style won't flash. **Edit:** first match in google search is the duplicated answer: